# how to make .htaccess rewrite all admin/ subfolders to admin/index.php and other to /index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, url-rewriting

So here is my situation.
I need to rewrite localhost/admin to admin/index.php ALSO localhost/admin/anysubfolder to admin/index.php

AND Also when you are at root localhost/ to /index.php and ALSO localhost/anysubfolder/subfolder whatever to /index.php
(just if its admin it would do previous rule)

currently i have

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php [NC]
```

this rule redirects localhost to localhost/admin and works with "admin" folders.
I am doing something very wrong, so please help me!

Comment: you can have one in your admin folder which will override the one in your web root.

Comment: **I am doing something very wrong** What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: Wouldnt it be possible to use one htaccess? I didnt think of using two. I will try that for sure. Thanks! And wrong was that i didnt think of placing second htaccess inside admin folder